# Renomeio a pasta, mas quando dou git push da erro

Tags: git, ubuntu

Quero uma ajuda, estou aprendendo LARAVEL,na seção de cadastro de produtos estava dando erro, o nome da pasta estava errado, era PRODUCTS e mudei para PRODUTOS até ai nenhum problema. Mas quando eu fui subir as alterações para o repositorio no BITBUCKET ele aparece esse erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei ainda da um `git pull` mas tambem não funciona!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente dar permissão no linux a pasta que você alterou, é pouco provável que o erro esteja no git.

```
chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/laravel/
```